# How to set Define off to a database/schema permanently in Oracle

Tags: oracle, variables, jdbc, system

I have a problem in setting "Set Define OFF" via JDBC as we can't run SqlPlus commands direcly from JDBC.

Is there any way to run that Set Define off to my database/schema permanently so that I can ignore '&' substitution variable.

Please suggest me more on this Oracle system environment variable settings permanently.

Comment: You can't do that.  Why do you have "&" literals in your queries?  Are these string parameters?  If so, then use proper JDBC parameter binding.  PLease show sample JDBC call sequence you are using that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently configure SQL*Plus, you can configure it for instance using login.sql or the global glogin.sql.

See [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/ch3.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to escape an ampersand character within your SQL using JDBC, then run the following method from the `Statement` class instance:

`statement.setEscapeProcessing( false );`

This will stop `jdbc` from attempting to perform Escape Processing.